# Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't support PEAP authentication without CA certificate

Tags: 16.04, authentication

In our college, we have PEAP authentication system for LAN Authentication. With the new Ubuntu update to 16.04, the PEAP Authentication asks for the password again and again and doesn't connect. It used to work perfectly in Ubuntu 14.04.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `nmcli` to add the password.

1. Edit `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/CONNECTION_NAME`:

   ```
   [connection]
   id=CONNECTION_NAME

   [802-1x]
   password=YOUR_8021X_PASSWORD
   ```
2. Restart your network

   ```
   systemctl restart NetworkManager
   ```
3. You may need to bring the interface down and up to test the new changes:

   ```
   nmcli con down CONNECTION_NAME
   nmcli con up CONNECTION_NAME
   ```

All the thanks are for this [source](https://major.io/2016/05/03/802-1x-networkmanager-using-nmcli/).