# 802.1x Certificate verification failed

Tags: networking, network-manager, security

I use 802.1x with PEAP Authentication and MSCHAPv2 inner authentication. And receive "unknown CA" error.
I have tried to install root CA using update-ca-certificates but it doesn't help.

Is it possible to get additional information about the problem or maybe just ignore certificate issuer?

Syslog:

```
wpa_supplicant[1380]: enp0s25: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED EAP authentication started
wpa_supplicant[1380]: enp0s25: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=25
wpa_supplicant[1380]: enp0s25: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-METHOD EAP vendor 0 method 25 (PEAP) selected
wpa_supplicant[1380]: TLS: Certificate verification failed, error 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate) depth 0 for '/C=RU/ST=RU/L=MSK/O=*COMPANY*/OU=ITSEC/CN=*hostname.com*/*email@hostname.com*'
wpa_supplicant[1380]: enp0s25: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-TLS-CERT-ERROR reason=1 depth=0 subject='/C=RU/ST=RU/L=MSK/O=*COMPANY*/OU=ITSEC/CN=*hostname.com*/emailAddress=*email@hostname.com*' err='unable to get local issuer certificate'
wpa_supplicant[1380]: SSL: SSL3 alert: write (local SSL3 detected an error):fatal:unknown CA
wpa_supplicant[1380]: OpenSSL: openssl_handshake - SSL_connect error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
wpa_supplicant[1380]: enp0s25: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-FAILURE EAP authentication failed
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed the steps from here and it worked for the above error.

Please use nmcli to add the password.

```
Edit /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/CONNECTION_NAME:
[connection]
id=CONNECTION_NAME




[802-1x]
password=YOUR_8021X_PASSWORD
```

Restart your network

systemctl restart NetworkManager

You may need to bring the interface down and up to test the new changes:

nmcli con down CONNECTION_NAME
nmcli con up CONNECTION_NAME

All the thanks are for this source:

[Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't support PEAP authentication without CA certificate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/765021/ubuntu-16-04-doesnt-support-peap-authentication-without-ca-certificate)